# Is "Now I came back" grammatically correct?

Tags: tense

Not sure if 'Now' is correct with 'came', as 'came' is a past verb. What's the appropriate thing to use?

Comment: Do you mean "I have just come back?"

Comment: It's not necessarily "wrong", but your *Now I came back* is an extremely unlikely utterance. Come to that, there aren't many contexts where one would say *Now I **come** back* - the most likely possibilities are ***Then I came back*** or ***Now I have come back***, but unless you can give us a much more complete context (including explaining *exactly* what you want to convey), I don't think this question can be usefully answered.

Comment: You can say "Now I am back"

Answer (score 2):

> Now I came back

grammatically has a correct structure, but semantically does not make sense.

> Now *that* I have come back...
> Now *that* I am back...

would have the meaning that I believe you are trying to convey. Specifically, it means that you have returned from *somewhere*.